# Gitting with a team

Tags: git

I'm developing an application and my friend wanted to join the development.
So I created a git repository on assembla.com , performed a push and invited him to work with me.

My question is about the working proccess. We both use git bash on msysgit.
I don't have problems with commit and push, the problem is with getting my friend changes. Why a simple pull does not work?

Comment: Going to need more info here (in particular what goes wrong when you pull or the friend pushes)

Comment: Nothing goes wrong, but nothing happens either

Comment: I found a command that do a merge with local and it works I wanna know I'm working correctly

Comment: Has your friend pushed changes? Can you see these changes on assembla.com? Are you both on the same branch?

Comment: yes yes yes... We did the entire process successfully, but had to use some special command that do merge from remote, why is that?

Comment: What was this "special command"? It would be incredibly helpful if you listed the commands you've used so far, such as how you cloned the repository, how you're committing, how you're pulling, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: I dont remember, sorry, 
I do remeber the command update from all remotes and also merge

Comment: @Chen if you use bash then you should have bash history. Use ctrl-r to search it, or use the history command, or grep through ~/.bash_history. If your friend pushed her changes successfully then you should be able to do a git-pull to get them into your branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer (judging from the comments):

```
git pull origin master
```

If that works as you're hoping, make it the default by adding this to your .git/config file:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

With that setup, you can then call:

```
git pull
```

...in future.

Long answer: It sounds like you haven't set up default merge targets.

You want a configuration setting that says, "Whenever I pull from remote repository X, automatically merge the changes with branch Y." (Typically, "When I pull from 'origin', merge with 'master'.") That's automatically set up when you do a 'git clone', but your working copy was created from scratch (not cloned) so you have to do it yourself.

You might find it interesting to compare your .git/config file with your friend's.